# How can I ask GCC to use a different standard library?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, std

I have a debug version of `libstdc++` 6 in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.
I would like to tell gcc/g++ to use this library instead of the standard library version without debug symbols.
I tried using `-nostdlib` and passing the library path explicitly with `-L`, but get linking errors such as

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tst_elfmap.dir/perfparser/tests/auto/elfmap/tst_elfmap.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

It seems that the library version (according to the file name) is the same for the debug and release builds of libstdc++ installed on my system:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 19 Oct  4  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
```

Comment: Have you tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`?

Comment: @NutCracker that seems to do the trick!

Comment: [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is open source. You can improve its source code and you should read documentation about [*Invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). If you use [cmake](https://cmake.org/) (see also [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)...) you should **read documentation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable like:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

This variable can be used to change the dynamic linkers search paths so, instead of searching for `libstdc++` in the system's library paths, `libstdc++` will be searched along `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.